# SQL Server: ¿Qué se hace cuando se te llena el disco?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Todavía no he tenido este problema, pero tengo miedo de que un día me pase y no saber que hacer.

Si tengo una base de datos en el disco C de mi ordenador, y ese disco por cualquier cosa, se llena, que hago?

Existe la posibilidad de que SQL Server guarde los datos de las bases de datos en 2 discos a la vez?

He estado buscando información al respecto pero no encuentro nada útil.

Gracias

Comment: Si, fijate estos links: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/add-data-or-log-files-to-a-database?view=sql-server-2017 y https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Pues te sugiero que no llenes el disco, si es una base de datos en producción, no deberías usar el disco de la misma en otras cosas que no sean tu base de datos. Saludos

Comment: eso se conoce como base de datos espejo

Comment: @JackNavaRow Las bases de datos espejo son para crear redundancia y alta disponibilidad, no para dividir una base de datos en múltiples discos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primero debes entender un poco como funciona el almacenamiento en SQL Server.

SQL Server tiene 3 tipos de archivos mdf, ndf y ldf (hay más pero esos son los básicos). Los archivos mdf y ndf son archivos de datos, ahí se guarda toda la información de la base de datos. Los mdf es el archivo primario y los ndf son archivos secundarios. Siempre tendrás uno (y solo uno) archivo mdf, pero puedes tener múltiples archivos ndf. Los archivos ldf son el log de transacciones. Puedes tener varios de estos, pero lo recomendable es que mantengas sólo uno.

Para definir en donde se guardan los datos, existen los grupos de archivos (filegroups) que es la forma de relacionar objetos de la base de datos (tablas, índices y vistas materializadas) con los archivos en los que se van a guardar. Más información de este tema en [la documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups).

Teniendo esos datos básicos, vamos a como se guarda la información.

(Este parrafo muestra un problema que llena el disco de forma innecesaria y como evitarlo).
Todos los cambios a la base de datos se guardan primero en el log de transacciones y luego en el respectivo archivo de datos. El log de transacciones seguirá creciendo hasta que se realice un respaldo del log y pueda comenzar a reutilizarse, o al final de cada transacción cuando el modelo de recuperación está definido como `simple`. El primer problema con almacenamiento que he visto con bases de datos mal administradas es que tienen el modelo de recuperación en `full` y nunca realizan respaldos del log. La solución a ese problema, depende de la cantidad de información que estén dispuestos a perder en caso de un desastre y su relación con el trabajo que deseen realizar continuamente.

El segundo punto es que los datos se guardan en la tabla directamente sin ningún orden lógico o físico, o se guardan en el índice clustered en caso de existir tal para obtener un orden lógico. Saber esto es lo que te ayudará a mover tablas de un disco a otro sin necesidad de copiarlas de la forma tradicional. Lo único que necesitas hacer es recrear el índice clustered en el grupo de archivos que deseas.

```
USE master
-- Crear el nuevo FILEGROUP
ALTER DATABASE BaseDatosEjemplo
ADD FILEGROUP NUEVO_FILEGROUP;  
GO  

-- Agregar un archivo al nuevo filegroup fuera del disco C  
ALTER DATABASE BaseDatosEjemplo   
ADD FILE   
(  
    NAME = ArchivoEjemploNuevo,  
    FILENAME = 'F:\MSSQL\DATA\ArchivoEjemploNuevo.ndf',  
    SIZE = 5MB,  
    MAXSIZE = 100MB,  
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB  
)  
TO FILEGROUP NUEVO_FILEGROUP;  
GO

USE BaseDatosEjemplo   
--Una vez creado el archivo y su grupo, podemos mover la tabla.
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX Indice_Clustered_De_Ejemplo ON TablaEjemplo (ID_TablaEjemplo)  
    WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)  
    ON NUEVO_FILEGROUP;
```

Hay mucho más que puedes aprender acerca del almacenamiento, pero creo que eso también va mucho más allá del alcance de esta pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, intentaré hacer lo que dices de los "filegroup". Un saludo @LuisCazares