# SqlServer2014 - Disco duro lleno

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

En un SQL Server 2014, el disco duro está lleno. ¿Cómo se pueden eliminar los tempdb.mdf mediante una sentencia o de alguna manera?
¿Al reiniciar el SQLServer se deberían borrar automáticamente esos archivos temporales?

Gracias.

Comment: Prueba con
CHECKPOINT;
GO;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
GO;
DBCC SHRINKFILE (TEMPDEV, 1024);
GO;

Answer (score 2):

¡Detente! tempdb.mdf es una base de datos del sistema. No la debes eliminar a menos de que quieras arruinar tu servidor.

Hay diferencias entre llenar el disco duro y llenar la base de datos. Puedes tratar de reducir el tamaño de los mdf según el espacio disponible en cada uno de ellos. Para ver el espacio disponible, puedes usar el siguiente script.

```
CREATE TABLE #FileSize
(BD NVARCHAR(128), 
    NombreArchivo NVARCHAR(128), 
    TipoArchivo NVARCHAR(128),
    TamanoActualMB DECIMAL(10,2), 
    EspacioLibreMB DECIMAL(10,2),
    EspacioUsadoMB AS TamanoActualMB - EspacioLibreMB
);
    
INSERT INTO #FileSize(BD, NombreArchivo, TipoArchivo, TamanoActualMB, EspacioLibreMB)
exec sp_msforeachdb 
'use [?]; 
 SELECT DB_NAME() AS BD, 
        name AS NombreArchivo, 
        type_desc TipoArchivo,
        size/128.0 AS TamanoActualMB,  
        size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, ''SpaceUsed'') AS INT)/128.0 AS EspacioLibreMB
FROM sys.database_files
WHERE type IN (0,1);';
    
SELECT * 
FROM #FileSize
WHERE BD NOT IN ('distribution', 'master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')
--AND FreeSpaceMB > ?;
    
DROP TABLE #FileSize;
```

Una vez con esa información, puedes recuperar espacio en disco reduciendo el tamaño de los archivos mediante el uso de `DBCC SHRINKFILE` cambiando el 7 por el espacio usado por tus datos:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (DataFile1, 7);
```

Recuerda que esto es solo una acción que se hace en caso extraordinario y no algo que se deba hacer de forma automática.

Por experiencia, es probable que tengas tus bases de datos en el modelo de recuperación completo y no estés haciendo respaldos del log, lo que hará que los archivos del log estén creciendo sin control. Ese es otro problema que creo que está resuelto en otra pregunta que trataré de encontrar para adjuntar aquí.

Otras preguntas y respuestas acerca de almacenamiento:

- [Crecimiento de log acelerado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/380377/crecimiento-de-log-acelerado/380438)
- [¿Qué se hace cuando se te llena el disco?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285782/sql-server-qu%C3%A9-se-hace-cuando-se-te-llena-el-disco/285797)